# How can store the terminal in tui-rs in a struct?

Tags: rust

I am trying to store the tui terminal in a app struct as a reference with the code

```
use std::io;
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
use termion::{input::MouseTerminal, raw::IntoRawMode, screen::AlternateScreen};
use tui::{Terminal, backend::{Backend, TermionBackend}};

struct App<'a, B: 'a>
where B: Backend
{
    terminal: &'a mut Terminal<B>,
}

impl<'a, B> App<'a, B>
where B: Backend
{
    fn new() -> Result<Self, io::Error>{
        let stdout = io::stdout().into_raw_mode()?;
        let stdout = MouseTerminal::from(stdout);
        let stdout = AlternateScreen::from(stdout);
        let backend = TermionBackend::new(stdout);
        let mut terminal= Terminal::new(backend)?;
        
        Ok(Self{
            terminal: &mut terminal,
        })
    }
}
```

But with type mismatch: mismatched types
expected mutable reference `&'a mut Terminal<B>`
found mutable reference `&mut Terminal<TermionBackend<AlternateScreen<MouseTerminal<RawTerminal<Stdout>>>>>`?

How can solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I see two problems here: the first is that you are storing the terminal as a reference for some reason, when I think you most likely just want to store it directly like `struct App<B> { terminal: B }`. Otherwise, your `new` function won't work since `&mut terminal` is a reference to a stack variable, and will become invalid when the method finishes.

Comment: The next issue is given by the error: the `new` method always provides the termion backend, even when a user requests a different backend (specified via the `B` parameter, e.g. `App<MyCustomBackend>` instead of `App<TermionBackend<...>>`). How do you want to solve this? You could try to somehow construct the specified kind of backend, but I think you'd probably rather just implement the `new` method for the termion backend (e.g. `impl App<TermionBackend<...>> { fn new() ...`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason I want this, is the result type is  too long to type and I want to some how extend the type.  I mix the ideas. BTW, how can I save the return type typing?

Comment: Maybe you could try something like `fn new() -> App<impl Backend> { ... }`, see if that works.